# Exploding string containing 0x in PHP

Tags: php, string

I've noticed something peculiar in some internal `php` functions.
Using PHP 5.6.26

```
$a = "1280x720";
$b = explode('x', $a);
```

$b array:1 [
  0 => "1280×720"
]

```
$c = strpos($a, 'x');
```

$c boolean false

This is most probably caused by 0x720 being viewed as a hex number in part of the internal workings of `explode` and `strpos`.

Mostly since it does work as intended with a resolution of "854x480" . .

Even things like `str_replace('x', 'separator', $a);` don't work for me.

Does anyone know of a way to reliably get width and height from a resolution string like "1280x720" in `php` because I've about exhausted my ideas . .

UPDATE: Yes, it was indeed a typo (or rather read-o) in some cases there was an x and in others × (the 'times' character) . .

Comment: explode works for me

Comment: [Cannot reproduce.](https://3v4l.org/H1bD6)

Comment: Well, `explode('×', "1280×720');` works well. You just made a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`×` and `x` aren't the same character. This is not a issue with PHP itself.

The first one is unicode multiplication sign, the other is just plain "x" character.

The following would work:

```
$a = "1280×720";
$b = preg_split('~[×x]~u', $a);

print_r($b);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1280
    [1] => 720
)
```